Enviar imagen que esta en la solucion por correo
Tengo un proyecto en el cual tengo que enviar correos electronicos, pero tengo unas imagenes que van dentro del cuerpo del mensaje, para las pruebas utilizaba una imagen dentro de una carpeta, pero no quiero dar permisos a todos los usuarios para que entren a la carpeta.
Dentro de la Solucion, hice una carpeta donde subi esas mismas imagenes.
Mi duda es, dentro del codigo donde creo el correo, como puedo agregar esas imagenes para que no tenga que dar permisos a los usuarios a la carpeta.
Este es el codigo que utilizé.
  var oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            var f = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var mailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

 mailItem.Subject = "Nueva Baja";
                String attachmentDisplayName = "MyAttachment";
                string imageSrc = @"\\nas\Aplicaciones\FS_Desarrollo\microrh2\404\Proyecto_RH\Aviso_Editado.jpg";
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment oAttach = mailItem.Attachments.Add(imageSrc, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, null, attachmentDisplayName);

                string imageContentid = "someimage.jpg";
                oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageContentid);
                mailItem.HTMLBody = String.Format(
    "<body>NUEVA BAJA.<br>Número Empleado: " + Id_Emp.Text + "<br>Nombre: " + Nombre_Empl.Text + "<br>Fecha Baja: " + Fecha_Baja.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "<br><br><br><img src=\"cid:{0}\"><br></body>", imageContentid);
mailItem.Recipients.Add("rxxxx");

mailItem.Send();```


O alguna otro opcion que me puedan ayuda.


3 cosas: 1. Las imágenes deberían estar almacenadas en algún lado en internet. 2. Enviar imágenes con rutas de una intranet, no serán visibles para quienes revisen el correo desde internet. 3. Ten mucho cuidado a quién le das acceso al NAS. Saludos.

Si se envían por correo porque tendría que dar permisos a la carpeta a alguien?? Simplemente debe leerlas y enviarlas como adjuntos no ??? De mas contexto de como funciona la aplicación , las imágenes  siempre son las mismas o cambiantes ?La aplicación se instala localmente en la maquina del usuario ?
